# mutt: thread sorted by last activity, but mails sorted chronologically

Tags: mutt

My ideal configuration would be:

- threaded conversations
- sort threads in order of most recent mail in thread (thread: "last activity" order)
- sort mails within thread in order they were sent (mail: chronological order)

I seem to only ever be able to get 2 out of these 3…
The best I managed to get is with these settings:

```
set sort = threads
set sort_aux = last-date-sent
```

This gives me threaded conversations, with threads sorted by last activity, but this `sort_aux` makes mails within each thread appear in a weird order (AFAICT: order of the last leaf in each branch).

Is there any way to keep mails in chronological order, or does mutt not support?

Comment: I dunno, I think it might partly go against the whole principle of a threaded view, which is basically a tree with parent–child relationships between messages.

Comment: I still want the tree, I just want the node to be sorted by their own timestamp, not the one of their leaf :)

Answer (score 2):

With Mutt 2.2 this is now possible via the new config option `sort_thread_groups`: http://www.mutt.org/relnotes/2.2/

E.g. you can use:

```
set sort                = threads
# how threads are sorted in relation to other threads
set sort_thread_groups  = last-date-sent
# controls how the branches of the thread trees are sorted
set sort_aux            = date-sent
```

This will sort threads according to their latest sent descendant - so the thread with the latest reply is sorted last/newest - but messages within a thread are sorted compared only to their direct siblings (missing the `last-` prefix). So for example: if you get a patch-sets, the individual patch-sets get sorted according to their latest reply in the discussion, but the (top-level) patches within each patch-set are sorted according to when they were send originally (I hope that makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been [added to neomutt](https://neomutt.org/feature/use-threads), although not yet in a release as of this post.

To sort the "most-recent-activity" to the bottom, but keep posts within the thread in chronological order, you'd use

```
set use_threads=yes sort=last-date sort_aux=date
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this ?

```
set sort_aux = last-date-received
```

Comment: If you are certain this would solve the user's issue, then don't say "maybe?". If you are not certain, write it in a comment instead.

Comment: Sorry !
Thanks, I will care.